# Как сделать добавление элемента в конец с эффектом спойлера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я знаю, что для спойлера есть функция .slideToggle и для добавления в конец .append, но не могу понять, как их совместить.
Нужно, что бы кусок текста добавлялся в конец, и по второму нажатию убирался (удалялся в последствии).

Comment: Выложите свой код

Comment: Кода нет, я же говорю не понимаю как совместить

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
let w = "<p>Where is h4?</p>";
$(w).hide().appendTo('section').fadeIn(4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <h5>h5</h5>
  <h6>h6</h6>
</section>
```

И по нажатию..

```js
let w = "<p class='question'>Where is h4?</p>";
$(w).hide().appendTo('section').fadeIn(4000);
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.question').fadeToggle(4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <h5>h5</h5>
  <h6>h6</h6>
</section>
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```